# How can I replace {0} but not {{0}}?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I want to replace all `{0}` on a string with `x`. It should not match `{{0}}`.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Match either `{{0}}` or `{0}`, and replace only those occurances that are `{0}`.

Something like:

```
s = s.replace(/(\{\{0\}\}|\{0\})/g, function(m){ return m == '{0}' ? 'x' : m});
```

Comment: +1 For not suggesting the "let's make this regex super complicated!" path