# Is there a C# String.Format() equivalent in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

C# has the really powerful `String.Format()` for replacing elements like `{0}`with parameters. Does JavaScript have an equivalent?

Comment: There's no built-in equivalent, but you may google for external libraries.

Comment: Another option is CoffeeScript, which has Ruby style string interpolation.

Comment: a solution that allows for argument formatting, based on actual .net code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534803/string-format-in-javascript

Comment: [That](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038746/equivalent-of-string-format-in-jquery)'s the wrong duplicate. This is a question about string.format in **JavaScript**, and the dupe is for **jQuery**. `JavaScript !== jQuery`. There's not even a jQuery tag. You could argue [this question ("JavaScript equivalent to printf/string.format") is the correct "original"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format), but the currently linked one isn't.

Comment: `'{name} is {mood}'.replace('{name}', 'Tobi').replace('{mood}', 'happy')`

Comment: We're looking for a __non-jQuery__ answer. How can you mark the jQuery post as a duplicate for this question? That's supremely ignorant on part of those collective users who voted to close this off. Voting to reopen, btw.

Comment: So the correct answer is "no". Thanks for marking it as duplicate of a completely different question where everyone actually ignores the jquery part and modifies the string prototype with some custom code... the answer is just no, there isn't. You can write one, sure, but there isn't one built in.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Try [sprintf() for javascript](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf).

Or

```
// First, checks if it isn't implemented yet.
if (!String.prototype.format) {
  String.prototype.format = function() {
    var args = arguments;
    return this.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function(match, number) { 
      return typeof args[number] != 'undefined'
        ? args[number]
        : match
      ;
    });
  };
}

"{0} is dead, but {1} is alive! {0} {2}".format("ASP", "ASP.NET")
```

Both answers pulled from [JavaScript equivalent to printf/string.format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format)

Comment: a solution that allows for argument formatting, based on actual .net code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534803/string-format-in-javascript

Comment: If you don't want to extend the prototype:

`export class String {
  //String.format("{0} comes before {1}", "a", "b")
    static format(stringToFormat, ...tokens) {
        return stringToFormat.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function (match, number) {
            return typeof tokens[number] != 'undefined' ? tokens[number] : match;
        });
    };
}`

Comment: Yeah, I think it's a bad practice to extend the prototype of standard objects.

Comment: Basically Logic is 
`return stringToFormat.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function (match, number) {   
      return typeof tokens[number] != 'undefined' ? tokens[number] : match;    
  }); `

you can put this in normal method just like below :
`function format(stringToFormat, ...tokens) {        
  return stringToFormat.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function (match, number) {   
      return typeof tokens[number] != 'undefined' ? tokens[number] : match;    
  }); 
};
`

Answer (score 32):

I am using:

```
String.prototype.format = function() {
    var s = this,
        i = arguments.length;

    while (i--) {
        s = s.replace(new RegExp('\\{' + i + '\\}', 'gm'), arguments[i]);
    }
    return s;
};
```

usage: `"Hello {0}".format("World");`

I found it at [Equivalent of String.format in JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038746/equivalent-of-string-format-in-jquery)

UPDATED:

In ES6/ES2015 you can use [string templating](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) for instance

```
'use strict';

let firstName = 'John',
    lastName = 'Smith';

console.log(`Full Name is ${firstName} ${lastName}`); 
// or
console.log(`Full Name is ${firstName + ' ' + lastName}');
```

Comment: Although string templating is a nice feature, it's not the same thing. You can't store the string in memory or otherwise (in a registry for example) and use it with whatever inputs at a later point during runtime.

Answer (score 17):

Based on @[Vlad Bezden](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21844011/3449620) answer I use this slightly modified code because I prefer named placeholders:

```
String.prototype.format = function(placeholders) {
    var s = this;
    for(var propertyName in placeholders) {
        var re = new RegExp('{' + propertyName + '}', 'gm');
        s = s.replace(re, placeholders[propertyName]);
    }    
    return s;
};
```

usage:

```
"{greeting} {who}!".format({greeting: "Hello", who: "world"})
```

```js
String.prototype.format = function(placeholders) {
    var s = this;
    for(var propertyName in placeholders) {
        var re = new RegExp('{' + propertyName + '}', 'gm');
        s = s.replace(re, placeholders[propertyName]);
    }    
    return s;
};

$("#result").text("{greeting} {who}!".format({greeting: "Hello", who: "world"}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Great, much more suitable for formatting when there are multiple variables passed.

Answer (score 15):

I created it a long time ago, [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4280142/340760)

```
String.Format = function (b) {
    var a = arguments;
    return b.replace(/(\{\{\d\}\}|\{\d\})/g, function (b) {
        if (b.substring(0, 2) == "{{") return b;
        var c = parseInt(b.match(/\d/)[0]);
        return a[c + 1]
    })
};
```

Comment: This seems to be a better answer since it's not messing with the `prototype`.

Comment: Nice, sample usage: String.Format("Hello {0}. The meaning of life is {1} !", 'World', 42);